Is there a way to debug which theme is affecting a given component on an xml layout
I have been to numerous Stack Overflow pages looking for answers to change the hint colour when a text input layout is active. Despite having a custom theme there is a default value overriding my preference.
All I want now is a way to do "inspect element" and see exactly what property is affecting the active hint color and why it isn't my accent color.
My Style:
    <style name="EditTextHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

textInputLayout snippet (all are virtually identical:
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/EditTextHint"
    android:id="@+id/til1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:singleLine="true" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

Here is the outcome:


Try this,
Create a style in your styles.xml
<style name="TextInputStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="helperTextTextAppearance">@style/HintTextAppearance</item>

</style>

You can add hintTextColor, strokeColor or other customization you want your TextInputLayout to look like.
A style for your Hint text with your color and size if you want, use this in TextInputStyle (or you can apply this style directly to TextInputLayout itself)
<style name="HintTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/caption_size</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
</style>

Apply this style TextInputStyle to your TextInputLayout,
Let me know if it worked

I'm curious to learn more about typical usage for the following:
@dimen/caption_size. I deleted that line as i didn't have a value for it and there is a noticeable decrease in font size but finally I have control over the hint text colour. Now i just need to change the cursor colour and the underline

You can create a dimens.xml file in res/values -> add different sizes for your screen, caption_size, body_size etc.,
<dimen name="body_size">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="caption_size">9sp</dimen>
<dimen name="caption_size_medium">7sp</dimen>

Similarly, for res/values-sw600dp --> add dimen.xml with dimensions for 600dp screens, also res/values-sw800dp --> add dimen.xml with dimensions for 800dp screens vice versa...
Handling font sizes for different screens,..
